# making sense of a very basic inequality proof in an intro analysis textbook

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation

This is an excerpt from an Analysis textbook by Jospeh Taylor.

[proof from the book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MulKI.png)

The author gets to line (2.1.1) and writes "If we interchange ...... also holds." I don't understand this step in the proof. Why is the author adding an additional $|b|$ to both sides? Can you explain this section of the proof?

Why can't the author just write something like: $|a|-|b| ≤ |a − b|$ holds for all real $a,b$ and $|a-b|=|b-a|$, therefore $|b|-|a| ≤ |a − b|$. Multiplying by $-1$ we get: $-|a − b| ≤ |a|-|b|$. Finally, $-|a − b| ≤ |a|-|b| ≤ |a − b|$ and therefore $||a|-|b|| ≤ |a − b|$. Note that the very last step is already proven in the text.

can someone help me make sense of the author's argument?

Comment: See just the previous line. This is an explanation. If $x\geq y$ so for any $z$ we have $x+z\geq y+z$.

Comment: Summand $|b|$ is not needed in last inequality. May be typo.

Comment: can anyone confirm that summand |b| is a typo? are you sure?

Comment: Formally last inequality is correct, because it is true without summand $|b|$, so with it, of course inequality holds, but result does not need it.

Comment: @peanut Yes, it's typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $|a-b|\geq|a|-|b$, we obtain $|b-a|\geq|b|-|a|$, which says $$|a-b|\geq|a|-|b|$$ and $$|a-b|\geq-(|a|-|b|),$$ which gives $$|a-b|\geq||a|-|b||$$
We used the following.

> If $x\geq y$ and $x\geq-y$ so $x\geq|y|.$

This statement you proved in your post: Because it's $-x\leq y\leq x$.

Also, $$|a-b|+|b|\geq|b|-|a|$$ it's typo.

It should be $$|a-b|\geq|b|-|a|.$$

Comment: I understand why |a−b|≥|a|−|b|. I don't understand  what is below (2.1.1) in the proof.

Comment: how does |a−b|≥|a|−|b| combine with |b|-|a|≤|b|+|a−b| to get  the result?

Comment: @peanut  I added something. See now.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg. Question is about summand $|b|$ in last inequality in right side, on the image.

Comment: @zkutch  See please a previous comment of  peanut

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg. I saw your last comment about typo. That's why I wrote you. I think, if you add this to answer, then OP can accept it as correct one, which explains everything.

Comment: @zkutch Yes, now I see it.  Thank you! I just did not see it! :)